# Moving to Debian from Windows 7

Tags: debian, ntfs, ntfs-3g

Does Debian recognize Windows 7 formatted hard drives?

I am currently using Windows 7 and I want to switch to Debian 7.2 and I have lots of important files on D and E drives.

So should I have to format only C drive or all (if Debian won't recognize other drives) for installing Debian?

Comment: You can read/write NTFS/FAT partitions from recent Debian/Ubuntu distros (and probably many more) but it's not recommended for heavy use for its lack of recovery mechanism supports (for instance sometimes `ntfs-3g` mounts the partition read-only and make you reboot to windows for a `chkdsk` when encountering some errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Debian will be able to read and write from/to NTFS formatted drives with the ntfs-3g package.
If I recall correctly, that package is installed by default, but if it's not, it's a simple command to install it - `apt-get install ntfs-3g` off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can safely dual boot both system. You can repartition your C: drive to hold both systems. Simply disconnect your D: and E: drive from the motherboard to be on the safe side. You can't accidentally format them if they aren't connected. When you are done installing just reconnect your D: and E: drives. They will show up normally in both systems.